# How to add "Duplicate" to Windows 8/10 context menu

Tags: duplicate, context

I work between Mac and Windows all day mostly with Creative Cloud products. One item I really miss on windows it the simple 'duplicate' command. Context or CMD+D on a Mac.

I know I can copy and paste but I would like a similar command between the two environments. Is it possible? I've done some searching and I am familiar somewhat with adding items to context menu but I guess I would need a script or batch to run on the highlighted item and the context command to only be available if an item is selected and lastly, if possible, the ability to use the hotkeys Ctrl+D

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Yes it's possible, and your suggested way sounds quite plausible. Having said that, what's your specific technical question to us?  Where are you getting stuck exactly while implementing it?

Comment: I know how to create a context menu item to run a program, or batch file -- and it's quite easy to duplicate a file too -- but you would need to know how to _grab what the user is right clicking on_. That's out of my scope of knowledge, which is why I can't answer. I'm going to do some research and see if I can't figure it out though.

Answer (score 0):

there's someone who asked this question before, here's the link:

**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413014/custom-context-menu-option-for-duplicating-selected-file-not-working-as-expected**

This answer is the closest answer to your question.

To use it:

Step #1: Create an empty text file.

Step #2: open it and paste the following script in it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Duplicate File]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Duplicate File\command]
@="cmd /Q /V:ON /E:ON /C \"set TIME=%%TIME: =0%% & set DateTimeFn=%%DATE:~10,4%%-%%DATE:~4,2%%-%%DATE:~7,2%%_!TIME:~0,2!-!TIME:~3,2!-!TIME:~6,2! &FOR %%G IN (\"%1\") do copy \"%1\" \"%%~nG_!DateTimeFn!%%~xG\" & pause>nul\""
```

Step #3: Save the file as .reg extension to allow it to add the option to the registry.

Step #4: Double-click it, and give all required permissions.

Voila

[image: Duplicate file option]